# React get Laravel Auth User

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication

I just did the Auth system through Laravel and I'm facing a problem : how to check in ReactJS the logged user? I need to get his ID to check if this user can modify the page. I don't know where to go at all.

Any tips would be welcome!

Comment: You don't actually need to do that. Just make the request (using an API token from [Laravel's built-in API authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport) and let Laravel do the checks (using [Laravel's *authorization* system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authorization)). If it fails the checks, React will get a `403 Unauthorized` error and act accordingly.

Comment: But what about if I'm making some other things like profile modification that has nothing to do with ReactJS?

Answer (score 1):

you can't use the default authentication (using sessions) with a react app.

what you need is a system that creates an **authentication token** ( search for JWT or Laravel passport ) which identifies users, and since the HTTP protocol is stateless, in each request you must send that token to you backend service / API.

you can of course add a value representing the authentication ( true if you got a valid token ) to your global state just for UI or routing purpose.

check this [medium article](https://medium.com/@Gbxnga/token-based-authentication-with-react-and-laravel-restful-api-83f16581e85)  where the author explains how to create a token based auth with laravel using JWT.

you can also search about REST and oauth for more information.

Comment: The fact is my application can be used for other things that only the React part (which represents 50% of the whole application), and I don't know how to manage that with authentication token since I'm not going to use sessions

Comment: i've edited my answer by adding a link to a good medium article.

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is still kind of messy in my head: would it significate that I would have to log through React only?

Comment: you"re saying that your app is half HTML, half react right ?

Comment: Kind of. Half is some Laravel blade views with profile modification etc... And half is a ReactJS application. User is connected for the whole application and not only one part.

Comment: you should use the token based auth in all your application, i'll try to give you some links on how to do it when you"re fetching HTML files. edit : actually you can also return html files directly using api routes, just like web routes. https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/responses#view-responses

Comment: Currently I use Laravel blade login form (https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/authentication). After login, the rest is handed to React app. The problem is when I want to implement logout mechanism. Redirecting to login route doesn't result in expected result. Now I think if I implement the login form at the clien-side, the logout mechanism is easier to implement using React-Router's history and push. But this means, I have to change authentication mechanism using either JWT or Passport, which will take more effort and time.